# ''What of her''

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, differences

While watching an episode of Tidelands I paid attention to ''What of her?'' . Can anyone explain me the difference between ''what about her'' and ''what of her''? is it gramatically correct? In what regions is this phrase used?

so here is part of a dialogoue: 
A)-Cal McTeer B -what of her? A-I want you to seduce her

Answer (score 1):

To my ear (British English speaker) they mean the same. *What of her?* sounds old fashioned or literary to me.